# Toeplitz matrix, definition not well understood

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, toeplitz-matrices

I was reading about Toeplitz matrix and found the following:

> If the i,j element of A is denoted Ai,j, then we have
>
> Ai,j = A i+1,j+1 = a i-j

So I understood that `Ai,j = A i+1,j+1` which means that every member is equal to the member one row and one column after, but what about the following symbol: `a i-j` I don't understand it at all.

I mean each member has row index and column index but this symbol has one index.

Comment: The definition you have written is not complete. The omited part is equally important. Write a Toeplitz matrix. You'll see that "the the first row and/or the first column elements" are enough to fully define the matrix. To this relates $a_{i-j}$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe because of the structure of the Toeplitz matrix, you can assign a single index for the diagonal entries because along any given diagonal, the value is the same.  For example, for a $3 \times 3$ case the pattern is:

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{0} & a_{-1} & a_{-2} \\
a_{1} & a_{0} & a_{-1} \\
a_{2} & a_{1} & a_{0} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This idea generalizes to other matrices.

More details here at wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix.  I hope this helps.